# 404 error when i try to call rest service using Ajax

Tags: java, ajax, spring, rest, deployment

Show 404 error when i try to call rest service using Ajax.

War file name  : Document

Server side url Mapping,

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value =  "/document/document/download.ws")
    public HttpEntity<DownloadDocumentResponse> downloadDocument(
            @RequestBody final DownloadDocumentRequest downloadDocumentRequest) throws Exception {
        final DownloadDocumentResponse downloadDocumentResponse = documentWs.downloadDocument(downloadDocumentRequest);
        downloadDocumentResponse.setApplicationContext(null);
        return new ResponseEntity<DownloadDocumentResponse>(downloadDocumentResponse, HttpStatus.OK);

    }
```

client side Url : "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/document/document/download.ws"

Comment: Try with:
http://localhost:8080/Document/document/document/download.ws

Answer (score 0):

I think its a path error. The path to your domain is not written correctly

Comment: You should comment instead of posting answer.